# composition of functions and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We've proved that if $g$ is continuous at $c$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(c)$ then $f \circ  g$ is continuous at c.

I was wondering that if $g$ is continuous at $c$ and $f \circ g$ is continuous at c. Must $f$ be continuous at $g(c)$? I can't find a counter example to it, so I'm assuming it's true but having no luck proving it

Comment: Not necessarily but it may be difficult to find a simple example. Check this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240575/continuous-composition-with-one-discontinuous-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. That is,
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$

If $g$ is continuous at $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f\circ g$ is continuous at $c$, then $f$ is continuous at $g(c)$. **Not true**. Let's see why. We first go through the logic, then we provide an example.

Assume the following:
(i) $g$ is continuous at $c$
(ii) $f\circ g$ is continuous at $c$

By (i), for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|g(x)-g(c)|<\epsilon$.

By (ii), for each $\lambda>0$, there exists $\eta>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $|x-c|<\eta$, then $|(f\circ g)(x)-(f\circ g)(c)|<\lambda$.

We want to show that for each $\xi>0$, there exists $\sigma>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $|x-g(c)|<\sigma$, then $|f(x)-f(g(c))|<\xi$.

Let $\xi>0$ be arbitrary. Now we want to show that there exists $\sigma>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $|x-g(c)|<\sigma$, then $|f(x)-f(g(c))|<\xi$.

We know the following:
(I) there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|g(x)-g(c)|<\xi$.
(II) there exists $\eta>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $|x-c|<\eta$, then $|(f\circ g)(x)-(f\circ g)(c)|<\xi$.

In other words:
(I) If $x$ is close enough to $c$ (how close? $\delta$ close), then $g(x)$ is as close as we want to $g(c)$.
(II) If $x$ is close enough to $c$ (how close? $\eta$ close), then $(f\circ g)(x)$ is as close as we want to $(f\circ g)(c)$.

We have a problem! We cannot say anything about how $f$ behaves when $x$ is really close to $g(c)$!

## An Example

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x\text{ is rational}\\
0&\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$
This function is called **Dirichlet's function**.

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{q}&\text{if }x\text{ is rational, in which case }x=\frac{p}{q}\text{ in lowest terms and }q>0\\
0&\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$
This function is called **Thomae's function**. It is continuous at every irrational number!

Notice for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $(f\circ g)(x)=1$. It is a constant function! Therefore it is continuous.

Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ be any (I mean *any*) irrational number. Is $f$ continuous at $c$? No. As a matter of fact, $f$ is discontinuous everywhere! But $g$ and $(f\circ g)$ are continuous at $c$. Therefore the above statement has been *proven* to be not true.

I hope my long-winded answer not only answered your question, but also informed you of the logic behind **continuity**, and what it truly means.

Answer (score 1):

Try these at $0$:
$$ \eqalign{g(x) &= x^2\cr
f(x) &= \cases{1 & if $x \ge 0$\cr
               2 & if $x < 0$\cr}}$$

Answer (score 0):

*G* emphasized text denotes "*g* is continuous at *c*"

*F* denotes "*f* is continuous at *g*(*c*)"

*C* denotes "*f* o *g* is continuous at *c*"

Sentential Calculus says:

> (((*G* --> (*F* --> *C*)) --> ((*G* ^ *F*) --> C))) Through Importation

Which is the axiom of closest resemblance to your situation, but unfortunately it doesn't say much about :

> (((*G* ^ *F*) --> C) --> (*G* --> (*F* --> *C*)))

As nothing can be concluded by the converse of this statement.

So in other words, nothing can be conclude from "if g is continuous at c and f∘g is continuous at c."

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is the characteristic property of embeddings resp. quotient maps, that is:

A map has the characteristic property of embeddings if:
$$f\text{ continuous}\iff \iota\circ f\text{ continuous}$$
Especially this requires the embedding to be continuous.

A map has the characteristic property of quotient maps if:
$$g\text{ continuous}\iff g\circ\pi\text{ continuous}$$
Especially this requires the quotient map to be continuous. *(That is the situation of your question.)*

Besides, the embedded spaces resp. 'quotiented' spaces are precisely what we call subspaces resp. quotient spaces...